# postfix ISP blocked port 25

Tags: postfix

My ISP blocked port 25. I am unsure how to get port 587 working.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klyXe.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Snx7F.png)

Comment: Welcome to SE. This answer (https://serverfault.com/a/97499/413448) might be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Well... Some ISP have made a workaround to the whole port 25 is blocked - maybe the same for you?

Speaking from experience.

One of my former ISP had in their FAQ the information that I have to make a change in DNS on the following format:

```
domain.com.      IN MX   10    smarthost.isp.com.
domain.com.      IN MX    20   mail.domain.com.

mail.domain.com.   IN A  your.public.ip.address
```

The way it works is all inbound mails will land ISP smarthost first and then be forwarded to your mailserver.

The ISP smarthost is essentially acting as a gateway through the ISP firewall this way.

Maybe your ISP have a similar approach?